# Extremely slow connection to a VPS

Tags: networking, vpn, speed, vps, wireguard

I use a (dedicated) VPS to host a Wireguard VPN server. Everything works, but I noticed that my connection caps at around 2.5MB/s.

When using `wget` on the server itself the transfer around 85 MB/s. My connection at home is 300/30 Mb/s and I can achieve those speeds.

Also, the connection is slow even when connecting to the VPS using WinSCP (directly, not via VPN).

**I wonder what can I do to utilize full connection speed.**

What I tried so far:

- Change VPS provider to be phsically closer to my location → Didn't really help...
- Fiddled with MTU settings both in Wireguard and on my PC → No effect also.